# how to convert an empty record to zero

Tags: sql, isnull

I am working on a Point-of-sale system, but I have been stranded lately.  I have two tables from which I want to pick data, but some of the values I retrieve are `NULL`s, whereas I need them to be zeros.  This happens when there is a row in one table (`[dbo.ProdDetails]`) without a corresponding row in the other table `[dbo.Pro_Sales]`.

I am using this query:

```
 SELECT a.ItemCODE,a.OpenStock,c.UnitsSold
 FROM
   (SELECT  x.ItemCODE,x.OpenStock FROM  dbo.ProdDetails x) a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN

   (SELECT  x.ProductID,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),x.Quantity),'') UnitsSold
    FROM  dbo.Pro_Sales  x
    GROUP BY x.ProductID,x.Quantity
    ) c
 ON a.ItemCODE=c.ProductID

 WHERE a.ItemCODE ='0005'
```

The result am getting is

itemCode  OpenStock UnitsSold
0005       6        NULL

Comment: Wrap the field you want to display 0 with ISNULL(c.UnitsSold, 0) as UnitsSold

Comment: Note that `ISNULL()` is a Microsoft extension.  Possibly a few other DBs support it, but many don't (Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, ...).  The `COALESCE()` function is standard, supported by all of the above, including SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL(columnName, alt.Value) as columnName:

```
SELECT a.ItemCODE,a.OpenStock,ISNULL(c.UnitsSold,0) as UnitsSold
 FROM
   (SELECT  x.ItemCODE,x.OpenStock FROM  dbo.ProdDetails x) a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN

   (SELECT  x.ProductID,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),x.Quantity),'') UnitsSold
    FROM  dbo.Pro_Sales  x
    GROUP BY x.ProductID,x.Quantity
    ) c
 ON a.ItemCODE=c.ProductID

 WHERE a.ItemCODE ='0005'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `COALESCE()` function is for:

```
SELECT a.ItemCODE, a.OpenStock, COALESCE(c.UnitsSold, 0) AS UnitsSold
FROM
  (SELECT  x.ItemCODE,x.OpenStock FROM  dbo.ProdDetails x) a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT  x.ProductID,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),x.Quantity),'') UnitsSold
   FROM  dbo.Pro_Sales  x
   GROUP BY x.ProductID,x.Quantity
   ) c
ON a.ItemCODE=c.ProductID
WHERE a.ItemCODE ='0005'
```

Comment: I think `isnull` might be slightly more accurate in this situation.

Comment: `ISNULL()` cannot be more accurate if it is not available.  If you happen to be using SQL Server, though (the main DBMS that provides it), then the only difference between `ISNULL()` and this use of `COALESCE()` is the rules for determining the data type of the result.  In the unlikely event that the data type of literal `0` has higher data type precedence than that of `c.UnitsSold`, and that the difference matters, either the `0` or the result can be cast to ensure the required data type.